# Taylor Series $(x+2)/(2-3x)$ at $x=2$

Tags: taylor-expansion

How can I find Taylor series for  $$\frac{(x+2)}{(2-3x)}$$ at $x=2$?

Comment: to those who want to close this why?.

Comment: Most probably because most members of this site expect each asker to show some self effort towards solving his own question. As you can see, also answers here and in other posts usually show only *part* of the work, leaving some work for the asker to complete.

Comment: the easiest way to do this is to make a change of variable $x = 2 + h.$

Answer (score 7):

Hints:

$$\frac{x+2}{2-3x}=(x+2)\;\frac13\;\frac1{2-x-\frac43}=-\frac{x+2}3\;\frac34\;\frac1{1+\frac{3(x-2)}4}=$$

$$=-\frac{x+2}4\left(1-\frac{3(x-2)}4+\frac{9(x-2)^2}{16}-\ldots\right)$$

Well, now find the general expression for the above and for what values of $\;x\;$ it is valid.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{hint}$
$$
f(x) = -\frac{1}{3x}\frac{x+2}{1-\frac{2}{3x}}
$$
so Taylor expand $$\left(1-\frac{2}{3x}\right)^{-1}$$ and then multiply by 
$$
-\left(\frac{1}{3} +\frac{2}{3x}\right)
$$

Comment: But how is this an expansion **around $\;x=2\;$** ??

Comment: @Timbuc First off I think your answer is nicer (+1) and to the point. But the expansion I give is satisfied when $\frac{3}{2} < x$ and clearly $x=2$ satisfies the convergence criteria.

Comment: that doesn't address my comment: the series, as asked and unless I'm missing something, **must** be given, if possible, as a power series of $\;x-2\;$ . Besides this, I think your series converges for $\;|x|>\frac23\;$ .

Comment: I can only assume that you are right in the assumption that he wants a power series of $(x-2)$ and your answer is even more correct than mine..but I thought he wanted a series that converges for $x=2$. But, looking at the OP question, it seems you are correct...cheers for that correction (oops!!).

Answer (score 0):

$$y=-1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{n+1}\frac{3^{n-1}(x-2)^n}{2^{2n-1}}$$

Comment: according to wolfram alpha it seems that $3^n$ should be $3^{n+1}$

Comment: @Parhs I think you mean $3^{n-1}$ not $3^{n+1}$, so I have edited it. Thanks